# How to set the background color of the git bash terminal

Tags: terminal, git-bash, mingw32

I would like to set the background color of my whole terminal. google didn't help.

The idea is to have it set to red when working in a prod context and black when in dev context.

Ideally would like to do it using the .bash_profile file where I have code to switch environment context.

Answer (score 0):

Console colors are stored in the registry under HKCU/Console/[window name]/ColorTable00-15.

[window name] is either "Git Bash" for the start menu entry or something like "C:_Program Files (x86)_Git_git-cheetah_.._bin_sh.exe" for the Windows Explorer context menu entry (supplied by Git-Cheetah).

Alternatively, the registry settings can be overridden by storing an NT_CONSOLE_PROPS structure with appropriate ColorTable settings in the "Git Bash.lnk" shortcut via IShellLinkDataList::AddDataBlock. This happens e.g. if you edit the properties of a console window started via shortcut, or if you edit the shortcut properties directly.

If you want the values from the registry instead, create a new "Git Bash.lnk" shortcut from scratch and leave the Options/Font/Layout/Colors tabs alone.

It seems the only way I can see so far is to manually edit the boxes from the properties window, but this is buggy and tedious - you can't use hex strings, and selecting the color to inspect it sometimes alters the color wildly.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qY86H.png)